# How do I configure my Google Drive App to be the default app for files it can open?

Tags: google-drive-api

I saw examples of some Google Drive Apps that when being installed, the user is asked should it be the default app for files it can open.
An example for such a dialog is: http://prntscr.com/1wan67

Unfortunately when my app is being installed, no such dialog is opened.

Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: What's your CWS entry? What mimetype you support? That dialog is by default shown after each install.

Comment: We use this mime-type: 'application/jbart'.
The CWS entry is called jBart, it is visible only for test accounts, should I open it for you ?
[Here is the Developer CWS link](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/developer/edit/jhkdklbfinbgfngjabdboilimojcfcil)
Application ID is: 225177759274.